# Exception handling in Spring XD streams

Tags: java, rx-java, spring-xd, project-reactor

How can you create a failsafe Spring XD stream, which will keep running properly after an exception is triggered for one specific message (i.e.logs the error but continues consuming the next messages in the stream), without having to add try catch(Throwable) in every Stream step?

Is there any easy way of doing this with the Reactor or RxJava model?

Example stream using Reactor:

```
@Override
public Publisher<Tuple> process(Stream<GenericMessage> inputStream) {
  return inputStream
      .flatMap(SomeClass::someFlatMap)
      .filter(SomeClass::someFilter)
      .when(Throwable.class, t -> log.error("error", t));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJava can be used by a processor module.  On creation the subscription needs to be created and to handle errors the subscriber needs to add an onError handler:

```
       subject = new SerializedSubject(PublishSubject.create());
        Observable<?> outputStream = processor.process(subject);
        subscription = outputStream.subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object outputObject) {
                if (ClassUtils.isAssignable(Message.class, outputObject.getClass())) {
                    getOutputChannel().send((Message) outputObject);
                } else {
                    getOutputChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(outputObject).build());
                }
            }
        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                logger.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
            }
        }, new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                logger.error("Subscription close for [" + subscription + "]");
            }
        });
```

Look at more examples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/spring-xd-rxjava/src